# condition in the SQL request

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL request:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID = Table1.Table2_iD
WHERE 
    *conditions*
    AND *idk how to describe it in sql*
```

I need a condition that will do something like this:

```
IF Table1.Date IS NOT NULL THEN
    Table1.Date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
ELSE 
    Table2.Date+2 months BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

I need your help my friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could COALESCE the Date Field like below. Coalesce checks for NULL values and then moves to the next value if it is null. It also works for N about of fields.

```
WHERE COALESCE(Table1.Date,ADD_MONTHS(Table2.Date,2)) BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is a bit messy, but I think you are looking for this:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN Table1.Date IS NOT NULL 
           THEN Table1.Date 
           ELSE ADD_MONTHS(Table2.Date, 2) END BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Or shorter:

```
WHERE COALESCE(Table1.Date, ADD_MONTHS(Table2.Date, 2)) BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a simple `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 t1
       JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.Table2_ID
 WHERE Table1.Date IS NOT NULL
   AND Table1.Date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
 UNION ALL
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 t1
       JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.Table2_ID
 WHERE Table1.Date IS NULL
   AND Table1.Date + 2 BETWEEN date1 AND date2;
```

since you will not render a possible index on Table1.Date unusable and have the same output. Performance-wise, it could potentially be better than using it with a function.